# Checking transform with cypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I'm new to cypress and I'm trying to check that one of my elements contains a specific style. The element is something like this:

```
<div class="myElement" style="transform: translate(0%, 0px); "></div>
```

An this is my assertion:

```
cy.get('.myImage').should("have.css", "transform", "translate(0%, 0px)");
```

This assertion is not working, but I cannot figure out why, cypress says:

```
expected <div.myImage> to have CSS property transform with the value translate(0%, 0px), but the value was none
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've also the similar issue => `expected 'MY_ICON_DOM' to have CSS property 'transform' with the value 'transform: rotateX(180deg)', but the value was 'matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1.22465e-16, 0, 0, -1.22465e-16, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cypress' `have.css` [uses](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Chai-jQuery) [chai-jquery](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-jquery#cssname-value) which asserts [*computed* value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Thus, even though you've assigned `translate(0%, 0px)`, it gets computed as `none`.

Alternatively, you could use assert like this:

```
cy.get('.myImage').should('have.attr', 'style').should('contain', 'transform: translate(0%, 0px)')
```

Comment: This doesn't work -> `expected MY_DOM to have attribute style` it seems that the attribute style is not found. actually the transform is applied via css, not inline